# how to keep toggle jQuery content at right side

Tags: toggleclass, jquery

I want to use toggle Jquery. I want to keep topic at left side of the page. When a user clicks on the topic, then that topic's related content should display at right side of page. Please can anybody provide a detailed explanation as to how to do that using toggle?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.topic').click(function() {
    $('.related-content', this).toggle();
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/umEYG/)**

Comment: thanks but can you explain me html tags fully. am bit confused @petersmith